# Axon QueryHandler timing problem, how to use initialResult() and updates() so i will only invoke one response

Tags: axon

I have a question about  the `QueryGateway.subscribtionQuery()`
We have a Query for an `aanvraagId`, which will respond with the corresponding `referentschapId`.

```java
    public void verwerkBeperkingErkenningsdoelGematcht(UUID aanvraagId,
                                                       UUID organisatieId,
                                                       UUID persoonId,
                                                       UUID erkenningId,

                                                       String grondslag,
                                                       Beperking beperking) {

        queryGateway.subscriptionQuery(FetchReferentschapAanvraagView.builder().aanvraagId(aanvraagId).build(),
                        ResponseTypes.instanceOf(UUID.class),
                        ResponseTypes.instanceOf(UUID.class)
        ).handle(referentschapId -> {
commandGateway.sendAndWait(RegistreerErkenningGrondslagEnBeperkingBijReferentschap.builder()
                        .referentschapId(referentschapId)
                        .organisatieId(organisatieId)
                        .persoonId(persoonId)
                        .erkenningId(erkenningId)
                        .grondslag(grondslag)
                        .beperking(beperking)
                        .build()
        );
                    },
                referentschapId -> {
commandGateway.sendAndWait(RegistreerErkenningGrondslagEnBeperkingBijReferentschap.builder()
                        .referentschapId(referentschapId)
                        .organisatieId(organisatieId)
                        .persoonId(persoonId)
                        .erkenningId(erkenningId)
                        .grondslag(grondslag)
                        .beperking(beperking)
                        .build()
        );
                }
        );
    }
```

The QueryHandler looks like :

```java
    @QueryHandler
    public Optional<UUID> getReferentschapIdVoorAanvraagId(FetchReferentschapAanvraagView fetchQuery) {
        log.info("getReferentschapIdVoorAanvraagId: %s".formatted(fetchQuery));
        return referentschapAanvraagViewRepository.findByAanvraagId(fetchQuery.getAanvraagId())
                                                  .map(ReferentschapAanvraagView::getReferentschapId);
    }

public class FetchReferentschapAanvraagView {

    private UUID aanvraagId;
}
```

and the Axon EventHandler:

```java
    @EventHandler
    public void referentschapGemaakt(ReferentschapGemaakt event) {
        referentschapAanvraagViewRepository.findById(event.getReferentschapId())
                                           .ifPresentOrElse(referentschapAanvraagView ->
                                                           log.warn(ER_BESTAAT_AL_EEN_REFERENTSCHAP_MET_ID_EN_AANVRAAG_ID
                                                                   .formatted(referentschapAanvraagView.getReferentschapId(),
                                                                           referentschapAanvraagView.getAanvraagId())
                                                           ),
                                                   () -> referentschapAanvraagViewRepository.save(ReferentschapAanvraagView.builder()
                                                           .referentschapId(event.getReferentschapId())
                                                           .aanvraagId(event.getAanvraagId())
                                                           .build()
                                                   )
                                           );

        queryUpdateEmitter.emit(FetchReferentschapAanvraagView.class, query -> event.getAanvraagId().equals(query.getAanvraagId()), event.getReferentschapId());
    }
```

The query is for a repository with the table:

```java
@Entity
public class ReferentschapAanvraagView {

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID referentschapId;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID aanvraagId;

}
```

Now is our situation as follows:

- 1st axon will get a **command A** to create an entry with aanvraagId=1 & referentschapId=2 and is stored in table `ReferentschapAanvraagView` with an AxonEvent and a `queryUpdateEmitter.emit` is performed.
- 2nd axon will do a Query QA with `FetchReferentschapAanvraagView.class` to  retrieve the `referentschapId` for a given `aanvraagId`.
  with the retrieved referentschapId a **command B** is given.
- 3th axon will do for 2nd time the Query QA to retrieve the referentschapId for a given `aanvraagId`.
  with the retrieved referentschapId a **command C** is given.
- 4th axon will do for 3th time the Query QA to retrieve the referentschapId for a given aanvraagId.
  with the retrieved referentschapId a **command D** is given.

Step 1 to 4 use al the same `aanvraagId`, and has one corresponding random generated `referentschapId` thus commands B,C and D use same referentschapId.
The commands B, C and D must only be executed once with the retrieved referentschapId.

(?) How can we quaranty that the commands B,C and D are only executed once?

The problem is that when we do the Query's QA whe don't know if the new entry in `ReferentschapAanvraagView` is saved in 1st step before the Queries `FetchReferentschapAanvraagView` for commands B,C and are performed.
It could that the entry is saved before, during and after the queries.
How can we achieve a query to handle this?
How we interpret the `queryGateway.subscriptionQuery().initialResult()` and the `queryGateway.subscriptionQuery().updates()`

- initialResult(): goes to the QueryHandler, reads table for `aanvraagId`, if data is saved for `aanvraagId` then return this data, return null otherwise.
- updates().subscruption(): responds every time an emit to the Query is given, in our case only once.
  So we where thinking to do an initialResult() if data present send command, if not do .updates().subscribe()
  Is this gonna work and how do we fix the subscription to execute only once?